Connecting to Oracle DB using Persistence.xml file
I have a Java application that successfully connected to an Oracle database. However, the database was recently upgraded and my connection does now not work.
I can connect to the new database using SQL Developer successfully. I noticed the TNSNAMES.ORA file that SQL Developer now uses has the following: (PROTOCOL = TCPS) whereas the old database connection within TNSNAMES.ORA only had (PROTOCOL = TCP). I'm assuming TCPS is a secure connection.
What do I need to change within my persistence.xml file for this new connection to work over TCPS? Or is there something else I need to do within the application to get this type of connection to work?
My persistence.xml connection values for the old database which worked is as follows:
<properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//testdb01:1521/test_app"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="testuser"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password01"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
</properties>


A wild guess: change the port in the url to 2484

Tried that and get the following error:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset


I got this working by doing the following:

Changed the jdbc.url value within the persistence.xml file to the following which allowed for the inclusion of the 'protocol=tcps' value:

jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=testdb01)(PORT=2484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test_app)))

The following website provided the solution: JDBC - Oracle FAQ

I downloaded the latest driver .jar file for Oracle 19c and added it to the Libraries folder within my NetBeans project.


So you're saying I would have been right had I also said update the driver to the latest? ;)

The easiest could be to generate a wallet on your server using orapki, install on your client, add "com.oracle.database.security:oraclepki" artifact to your build and then the URI to connect is "jdbc:oracle:thin:/@tnsname_entry_name?TNS_ADMIN=path_to_wallet"
See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/dbseg/using-the-orapki-utility-to-manage-pki-elements.html

Ty for this information. What I dont understand is why does the connection work with SQL Developer from my machine when I put the new details within TNSNAMES.ORA but it doesnt work with the Java application? I didnt add any certificates or anything to SQL developer or my machine for it to work??

SQLDeveloper has all the ORACLE libraries in its lib/ folders...

It seems that your database server is now configured to use secure connections only (i.e. the connection between the database client and the database server is now encrypted ~ TLS, SSL, etc) ...
I haven't experienced this myself, but throwing the right words at google (jdbc protocol tls oracle) I found these articles:
SSL Connection to Oracle DB using JDBC
Secured Communication (TCPS) Access to Databases
Sadly, this is no a straight answer, but it is good starting point. I would suggest reading the articles first and then create a small class that is able to connect to the database (using JDBC only, without the JPA persistence file) ...
Later, translate the working example to the persistence file: I presume that some of the described properties in those articles, need to be defined as properties in the persistence.xml.
Let us know how it works, Happy Coding ...

Ty for response. I was hoping it was going to be an easy answer :) No problem. I will take a read over those articles and make a start on Monday when I'm back in the office. I will provide an update once (if) I get it working :)
